# Return at least X results from split

Tags: python

[split](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) has a maxsplit parameter, which is useful when you want *at most* X results. If there something similar to return *at least* X results and populate the rest with `None`s. I'd like to be able to write

```
 a, b, c = 'foo,bar'.magic_split(',', 3)
```

and have `a=foo`, `b=bar` and `c=None`.

Any ideas how to write such a function?

Upd. I ended up with a solution which is a combination of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9294793/989121) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9294073/989121) answers:

```
>>> def just(n, iterable, fill=None):
...     return (list(iterable) + [fill] * n)[:n]
... 
>>> just(3, 'foo,bar'.split(','))
['foo', 'bar', None]
```

Comment: There is no *clear* way to do it, so you should do it. Use normal lists instead.

Comment: I agree with DrTyrsa, what's the background of what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such parameter to `str.split()`.  A hack to achieve this would be

```
a, b, c = ('foo,bar'.split(',', 2) + [None] * 3)[:3]
```

Not sure if I recommend this code, though.

Comment: you probably want to change `split(',', 2)` to `split(',', 1)`

Comment: @RomanBodnarchuk: The question has been edited, so I had to adjust my answer.  A bit confusing, I suppose.

Comment: Amazing! I think the second '2' should be '3' to handle an edge case empty arg + sep=None correctly.

Answer (score 5):

One way would be:

```
from itertools import chain
from itertools import repeat
from itertools import islice 

def magic_split(seq, sep, n, def_value=None):
    return list(islice(chain(seq.split(sep), repeat(def_value)), n))
```

You could just return the return value of `islice` if you don't need the list.

If you don't want the values to be cut off when n is less than number of split elements in seq, the modification is trivial:

```
def magic_split(seq, sep, n, def_value=None):
    elems = seq.split(sep)
    if len(elems) >= n:
         return elems

    return list(islice(chain(elems, repeat(def_value)), n))
```

Comment: You should pass `n - 1` as second parameter to `seq.split()`.

Comment: @SvenMarnach why? i just tested it and it works as described in the question.  `magic_split('foo,bar', ',', 3)` returns `['foo', 'bar', None]` so at least 3 elements, one of them `None`

Comment: Since for the use case `a, b, c = magic_split(...)` it is important that the return value of your function is *exactly* three items, not at least three items.

Comment: @SvenMarnach it is exactly three items. that's why the last operation is slicing. It will always return exactly n elements. Now there's a better reason for passing limit to split: to avoid splitting for sequences of many elements if n is small.

Comment: You are right about the length of the returned list -- the slicing happens after the splitting.  This will slice off parts of the original string, though -- try `"a,b,c,d"`.  The OP did not specify how to handle this case, so both approaches should be fine.

Comment: @SvenMarnach yeah, I assumed OP wants them cut off.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a more general function for that:

```
def fill(iterable, n):
    tmp = tuple(iterable)
    return tmp + (None,)*(n - len(tmp))
```

Then:

```
a, b, c = fill('foo,bar'.split(','), 3)
```

Comment: Thanks! Using a wrapper appears to be the cleanest solution

Answer (score 1):

Since you ask for a string method, you can start by deriving from str:

```
>>> class magicstr(str):
    def magic_split(self, sep=None, mlen=0):
        parts = self.split(sep)
        return parts + [None]* (mlen - len(parts))


>>> test = magicstr("hello there, ok?")
>>> test.magic_split(",", 3)
['hello there', ' ok?', None]
```